# python: Merge two 1D lists into one 1D list

Tags: python, list, merge

I want to merge two lists in the true sense of the word:

```
>>> l1 = [1,2,3,4]
>>> l2 = [9,8,7,6]
>>> merged(l1, l2)
[1,9,2,8,3,7,4,6]
```

I could easily to:

```
>>> m = []
>>> for i1,i2 in zip(l1,l2):
      m.extend([i1,i2])
>>> m
[1,9,2,8,3,7,4,6]
```

but I wonder if there's something more elegant?

ps: there are zillions of questions claiming to merge lists, but none that I found did this - apologies if I lost the real one in the mist!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[item for items in zip(l1, l2) for item in items]
# [1,9,2,8,3,7,4,6]
```

Or you can use `itertools.chain` like this

```
from itertools import chain
list(chain.from_iterable(zip(l1, l2)))
# [1,9,2,8,3,7,4,6]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and list comprehension:

```
>>> l1 = [1,2,3,4]
>>> l2 = [9,8,7,6]
>>> [x for xs in zip(l1, l2) for x in xs]
[1, 9, 2, 8, 3, 7, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
>>> l1 = [1,2,3,4]
>>> l2 = [9,8,7,6]
>>> sum(zip(l1,l2),())
(1, 9, 2, 8, 3, 7, 4, 6)
>>>
```

Comment: Using `sum` with non numeric types is generally a bad idea. In your case it will have quadratic performance

Comment: gnibbler could you please explain ? how it is O(n2) and why not with list comprehension ?

Comment: This method creates a tuple (1, 9), then (1,9,2,8), then (1,9,2,8,3,7) and finally (1, 9, 2, 8, 3, 7, 4, 6). Each time a new tuple is created, the previous values need to be copied over. Try it with lists of 40000 items each instead of 4 and you'll see a big difference.